# share html files on several pages without jQuery or fetch

Tags: javascript, html

I am wondering if there is a simple way to share html files (like the navbar, header, footer) across several pages (index.html, about.html, etc.) **without using jQuery or fetch** and instead using **html or JavaScript only**?

Assuming an 'index.html'-file and a 'common'-folder containing the 'navbar.html' and the 'footer.html':

- index.html
- common/navbar.html
- common/footer.html

How could I get the code from inside the navbar.html or footer.html get inserted into the index.html?

Comment: Make an [AJAX call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started) for the resource. But, really, this isn't a question for Stack Overflow. It's better as a question for Google.

Comment: @ScottMarcus – isn't fetch an asynchronous function? This is exactly what I would like to avoid as I am currently running into problems that the fetch() function doesn't get executed before my js modules are loaded, so that the elements inside the navbar.html files are not accessible by the functions inside my js modules (meaning: I can't access any <div> inside the navbar.html by using 'document.querySelector' inside the modules)

Comment: This is highly unusual, though you can use the plain old XHR object and event handlers to do that. look at this [link on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). This is old technology though, modern browsers all support fetch API. If you are trying to do a SPA, may I suggest a framework like angular or react. It's never a good idea to DYI on product environment. Also, you can do SSR if you serve requests using node, PHP, ASP, Java etc. (non-static).

Comment: @Cunning: so you would say that for static multiple page websites it would be better to repeat the code from the navbar.html on each page directly, without the suggested structure above?

Comment: @TimCc all remote requests are asynchronous, that's why they are implemented as Promises. You can then/catch them, or try async/await. You can learn more about Promises or async/await on online tutorials and YouTube videos. If you are restricted to an older ECMAScript standard, try using some transpilers like babel.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous by default and that is perfectly fine for your needs as you would only access the content in the success callback of the AJAX component.

Comment: @TimCc Right. If you are going to serve static files, and you don't want to repeat yourself, just try dynamically generate static contents on the server once, and serve them on a CDN or a cache or however you like. You can read more about this kind of techniques by searching keywords like `Server Side Rendering` and `Server Side Generation`.

Comment: What you are asking is extremely common when you have a server side programming language available to include various resources in a template file. Not clear if you have that availability or not

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`<object>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object) for that.

```
<object type="text/html" data="common/navbar.html"></object>
<div>my index.html</div>
<object type="text/html" data="common/footer.html"></object>
```